# debian/rule to remove directory?

Tags: makefile, debian

I'm writing debian/rules. And need to delete specific directories after installation such as `$ rm -rf /usr/lib/mytest/`

I'm refering to this doc But not able to find the way;

```
https://www.debian.org/doc/manuals/maint-guide/dreq.en.html
```

Can you please guide me?

Comment: I have no good knowledge of debian and package rules, but AFAIK rules are all the stuff, which happens in order to build a package, so IMHO if your last command there is to delete directory it should be deleted after the build.

Comment: Deleting something below `/usr/lib` **after installation** sounds like a very bad idea. In general, the place to do something after installation is the `postinst` script, [see here](https://www.debian.org/doc/manuals/maint-guide/dother.en.html#maintscripts)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found `preinst` script way.
Thanks.